# Joining two variable names and calling the resulting variable

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I want to be able to append a suffix to a variable name in pandas, and to have that suffix be able to change. In the line of code below, I want the mask variable name to be appended with var "lastyear".

```
dataavg1 = [np.median(df.query('mask == "%s"'%j)['continuousvar']) 
            for j in ('Value1','Value2')]
```

So essentially:

```
dataavg1 = [np.median(df.query('("mask"+lastyear) == "%s"'%j)['continuousvar']) 
            for j in ('Value1','Value2')]
```

I have tried a few variations on this and they all throw an error. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do all the string formatting *before* passing the string to `df.query`:

```
dataavg1 = [np.median(df.query('(mask%s) == "%s"'%(lastyear, j))['continuousvar']) 
            for j in ('Value1','Value2')]
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
col = 'mask{}'.format(lastyear)
dataavg1 = [np.median(df.loc[df[col] == j, 'continuousvar']) 
            for j in ('Value1','Value2')]
```

I think this is a little better, since the former computes the median of *all* the columns in `df` and then drops all the columns except `continuousvar`. 
The latter computes the median only for `continuousvar`, so it should be a little faster.

Comment: I used the second method and it worked perfectly. Thanks unutbu!